# @media doesn't work

Tags: css, media-queries

I was rewriting the style of my page for smaller screens using media queries :

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 400px) 
and (max-width : 1024px) {
#container {
right:10px;
top:50px;
font-size:24px;
position:absolute;
min-height: 85%;
margin-left:auto;
width:100px;
}   
#portfolio {
width:100px;
min-height:550px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;}
#whoami {
width:100px;
min-height:550px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;    }
#blog {
width:100px;
min-height:550px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;    
}
#contact {
width:100px;
min-height:550px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
box-shadow:  0px 2px 10px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

}
```

And NOTHING DID WORK AT ALL.. I viewed the webpage through my Dreamweaver CS6 compatibility view and it didn't work so I checked it by resizing my browser window and didn't work too.
Any ideas why didn't it work ? Doesn't it work with IDs ?!

Comment: Did you try it on a small screen?

Comment: You need to show more code or link to the problem page.

Comment: I've edited the question and entered the whole @media code.

Comment: So what’s the problem? A style sheet as such does nothing. If you add an element like `<div id="portfolio" style="border:solid">Some text</div>`, you’ll see that its rendering varies as you vary the browser window width.

Comment: But the width doesn't change, Its width is set in the normal style sheet as "650px" so it is supposed to change its width to 100px when I vary the browser window and that doesn't happen

Comment: I tested it using the exact code posted, with my simple HTML element, and the element changes width on Firefox, Chrome, IE 9 when window width is changed. You still have not provided a testable demo case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this meta on your header :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The code posted works as such, so the problem is elsewhere, e.g. in the rules inside the construct or in using a browser that does not support media queries (that would in practice mean IE 8 or older – otherwise [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) is very good).

To check out the situation, test first with a minimal document like

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Testing media queries</title>
<style>
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 768px) 
and (max-width : 1024px) {
  body { background: green; }
}
</style>
Hello world
```

You should also test the style sheet inside the construct by taking it out of, making it unconditional, to see whether it works at all.

Comment: I've edited the question and entered the whole @media code.
And I've tried your example and it works !!
Btw I'm using chrome and I don't think there's somebody on this planet who still use IE8 :D

Comment: You are half way retarded if you think nobody uses IE8.  And here's your code working (please resize your browser to see unstyled vs styled code): http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/3PPdh/

Comment: Offcourse I know I was just kidding, IE is still used by wide range of ignorant internet users who think that internet is only accessible by the IE.. China for instance

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me, too, on Chrome and Firefox.

I found that the problem arises when the default `visibility` is set to `hidden` or `display` to `none` (the visibility of the elements affected by css was controlled by js).